# Refer to subfields without specifing name in a mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a document of the form:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("1234"),
   "sources" : [
       {
           "accounts" : {
               "instagram" : {
                   "profile" : {
                       "provider" : "instagram",

                   },
                "facebook" : {
                   "profile" : {
                       "provider" : "facebook",

                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

It corresponds to the account a user with id 1234 has on social media let's say. So I would like to get the "provider" field of all items in sources. The problem is that I don't the exact name of the subfields of account as someone may have only instagram, another one facebook and instagram etc. 
So in order to retrieve those who have a facebook account, conceptually I would like to be use something like this:

```
db.social.find("sources.*.profile.provider": "facebook")
```

Is there something like a wildcard in mongo or another way to solve this problem ?

Comment: I believe accounts is defined as Array rather than Object (as mentioned in OP).

Comment: The document looks like exactly as in the description of the question. It is not an array

Comment: The above JSON is invalid. Unable to create document with it. Please provide valid JSON.

Comment: Maybe a silly question: But why is it invalid? I'm pretty sure that this is the document I get from my database but I can't handle it. Maybe there is a problem, so I would like you to help if possible